# Type argument 'CMSampleBufferRef' (aka 'struct opaqueCMSampleBuffer *') is neither an Objective-C object nor a block type

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, core-media

I want to store `CMSampleBufferRef` in mutable array for that I am trying to use below code

```
NSMutableArray<CMSampleBufferRef> *buffers;
```

But I am getting this error

```
Type argument 'CMSampleBufferRef' (aka 'struct opaqueCMSampleBuffer *') is neither an Objective-C object nor a block type
```

In swift we can write like this, it's working good

```
 var buffers = [CMSampleBuffer]()
```

I want to know how to write that in Objective-C and store sample buffers in mutable array. Suggest me solution for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674892/save-samplebuffer-in-array-avfoundation

Answer (score 0):

```
// defining the mutable array
NSMutableArray* sampleBuffers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// adding a sample buffer:
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = (...)
[sampleBuffers addObject:(__bridge id)sampleBuffer];
```

Note: Adding the sample buffer to the array will increment the retain count of the buffer; the retain count will be decremented when the buffer is removed from the array. Make sure the source of your sample buffers is fine with retaining the buffers for an extended period of time (some buffer pools might not like this).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will check with your process.